# blank element when trying to fetch the elements from html tag

Tags: php, html

I need some help with my php. I'm trying to fetch the list of elements from html tag called `streams`. When I try to fetch the elements from the html tags, it will not fetch it as it will show as a blank.

Here is the code:

```
<?php
   //ini_set('max_execution_time', 1000);
   error_reporting(0);
   //$errmsg_arr = array();
   //$errflag = false;
   $baseUrl = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/streams.php');
   $domdoc = new DOMDocument();
   $domdoc->strictErrorChecking = false;
   $domdoc->recover=true;
   @$domdoc->loadHTML($baseUrl);
   $links = $domdoc->getElementById('streams');
   echo $links;
 ?>
```

Here is the html source:

```
 <p id='channels'>BBC One South E</p><p id='streams'>http://www.example.com/live/35vlz78As8/191</p>
```

Can you please help me with how I can be able to fetch the elements from the id of the html tags?

Comment: how you show the result   ..  ??  please add  to your code

Comment: i am sorry but it show as a blank.

Comment: show the code you are using for print/echo the result

Comment: Please see the update code in my question.

Comment: `echo $links->nodeValue` will display the text content of the `streams` P tag. You mention a list in your question, but the source doesn't contain one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the @  at the begin of $domdc so you can see if some error happen and

You should use  textContent

```
$domdoc->loadHTML($baseUrl);
$links = $domdoc->getElementById('streams');

echo $links->textContent;
```

Comment: thank you very much for this as it is working great. I have got more than one element in my html source so how I can output for each element?